# Loading Wavefront Object with Lwjgl

Tags: java, lwjgl, wavefront

I would like to ask; how can one load a Wavefront object with lwjgl?

I have tried to write the code to accomplish this task but it doesn't seem to work.

Source code for what I have tried is located [here in GitHub](https://github.com/Isador34/Model)

If anyone knows how to render this model, I would be glad to hear from your suggestions.

Comment: I have got a lot of loading code because of a game I am creating (Here's a small screenshot: http://gyazo.com/759d22feb1b917144b418f47dbdd4ba5) - Would you want loading code that requires shaders but allows you to texture your models, or do you want an untextured model but with simpler code and no shaders? And yes, it's for OBJ files.

Comment: You know what - Just watch this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKFYtekgnP8 - It should contain everything you need. Feel free to ask about anything that confuses you. Though I am fine with just giving you the code if you want.

Comment: Thank for this video, I go try it

Comment: @Joehot200 - Why not move your comments to an answer so you can receive the reputation points and permit the question to be closed?